# How to undo expanding selection in Vim?

Tags: visual-mode, cursor-motions

I have this code snippet:

```
    await sendtemplateemail({
      recipient: invite.recipient_primary_email,
      templateid: 'd-******',
      templatedata: {
        inviteurl: `${process.env.frontend_url}/join/${invite_link}?ref=${invite.recipient_primary_email}&tk=community-p2p`,
        inviterfullname: invite.sender_first_name + ' ' + invite.sender_last_name, 
        peoplecount: isnan(communitypotentialconnections) ? 0 : communitypotentialconnections,
        communityname: community.name,
        communitypictureurl: community.logo,
        forceprod: true,
        portcosize: portcosize,
        portco1url: portcologos?.portco1url,
        portco2url: portcologos?.portco2url,
        portco3url: portcologos?.portco3url,
      },
    });
```

if i'm inside the innermost snippet (ie portco2url) and in vim i go into visual mode then type <kbd>a{</kbd> it selects everything inside the inner most brace ie this

```
{
    inviteurl: `${process.env.frontend_url}/join/${invite_link}?ref=${invite.recipient_primary_email}&tk=community-p2p`,
    inviterfullname: invite.sender_first_name + ' ' + invite.sender_last_name, 
    peoplecount: isnan(communitypotentialconnections) ? 0 : communitypotentialconnections,
    communityname: community.name,
    communitypictureurl: community.logo,
    forceprod: true,
    portcosize: portcosize,
    portco1url: portcologos?.portco1url,
    portco2url: portcologos?.portco2url,
    portco3url: portcologos?.portco3url,
}
```

If I immeditely type again <kbd>a{</kbd>  it selects the outermost brace

```
    {
      recipient: invite.recipient_primary_email,
      templateid: 'd-******',
      blindcopyto: ['testing@village.do'],
      templatedata: {
        inviteurl: `${process.env.frontend_url}/join/${invite_link}?ref=${invite.recipient_primary_email}&tk=community-p2p`,
        inviterfullname: invite.sender_first_name + ' ' + invite.sender_last_name, 
        peoplecount: isnan(communitypotentialconnections) ? 0 : communitypotentialconnections,
        communityname: community.name,
        communitypictureurl: community.logo,
        forceprod: true,
        portcosize: portcosize,
        portco1url: portcologos?.portco1url,
        portco2url: portcologos?.portco2url,
        portco3url: portcologos?.portco3url,
      },
    }
```

and so on, what I run one <kbd>a{</kbd> too many and I wanna go back to an earlier selection - in other words, how do i undo the last <kbd>a{</kbd>?

You can also see this in action here: https://asciinema.org/a/YuaSFgXBIVZ9Kij3lQAifP9k7

Comment: It's impossible with vanilla commands. Check out https://github.com/Matt-A-Bennett/vim-visual-history.

Comment: yeah that worked perfectly @romainl thanks!